# Disable Double-click event on VirtueMart2 checkout button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla2.5, virtuemart

Is there any solution to prevent double-clicking on the checkout button, so it wont checkout twice at the same time ? Because of this I have a lot of duplicated orders.

Filepath to working file is: `/templates/rolucia/html/com_virtuemart/cart/default.php`

Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code pls ?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#btnCheckoutSubmit').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            javascript:document.checkoutForm.submit();
            $(this).button('loading');
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="btnCheckoutSubmit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-warning" data-loading-text="..." href="javascript:document.checkoutForm.submit();">
    <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
    <?php if($this->checkout_task === 'confirm'):?>
        <?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CHECKOUT_CONFIRM');?>
    <?php else:?>
        <?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CHECKOUT_TITLE');?>
    <?php endif;?>
</a>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many tests, i found that only one approach which works is actually using `.bind()` or `.one()` functions. I used `bind()`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a#btnCheckoutSubmit').bind('click', function(e){
        $('#checkoutForm').submit();
        $(this).unbind(e);
    });
});
```

So, once submit button is clicked, after form submission it should unbind the event.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable your button after first click using [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#btnCheckoutSubmit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        javascript:document.checkoutForm.submit();
        $(this).button('loading');

        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't know about `.prop()`. it keeps sending as much as user clicks on that button, even without `href` attribute in a `<a>` tag